# React-Markdown Error: Must use import to load ES Module:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-markdown

I try to install `react-markdown` to my nextjs project, but getting instantly following error when I try to use it.

My Code:

```js
import React from 'react'

import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'

export function Markdown({ markdown }: { markdown: string }) {
  return (
    <article className="prose-sm">
      <ReactMarkdown>{markdown}</ReactMarkdown>
    </article>
  )
}
```

The error message:

```js
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/username/Projects/mono/node_modules/react-markdown/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /Users/username/Projects/mono/node_modules/react-markdown/index.js from /Users/username/Projects/mono/dist/apps/webapp/.next/server/pages/_app.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/username/Projects/mono/node_modules/react-markdown/package.json
```

[image]

I am using following Versions:
Node on `v14.17.5` and yarn `1.22.11` and my current Nextjs version is `^12.6.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found following solution on Github. [Here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25454#issuecomment-903513941)

You need to add `next-transpile-modules` to your `next.config.js` like following.

```js
// next.config.js

const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['react-markdown']);

module.exports = withTM({
...
})
```

and you need to import react-markdown like:
`import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown/react-markdown.min';`